# Missing mono vbc.exe in AlmaLinux 9

Tags: rpm, mono

I am running AlmaLinux 9 (clone of RH 9) and installed the available Mono packages.  I had to install an RPM from Fedora 38 to get vbnc.exe (from package mono-basic)

However, since vbnc.exe is deprecated the program I'm trying to run is asking for vbc.exe.  I can't find this available in ANY RH9 compatible RPM.

Any other CentOS9/RH9/AlmaLinux9/Rocky9 users have a solution to this?  Newer .NET VB programs will demand vbc.exe and it's nowhere to be found for this Distro.